# Response length inside the response itself

Tags: php, csv, response, string-length

We've got a PHP response script which outputs a string like this:

```
BEGIN;
00000087;
data1A;data1B;data1C;
data2A;data2B;data2C;
data3A;data3B;data3C;
END;
```

As you can see on line 2 the length of the response is sent inside the response itself. (The response length is used for validation purposes later on.)

At the moment we are padding the response length with leading zeroes to a total length of 8 characters to keep the calculation simple. So the code looks like this:

```
$sBegin = "BEGIN;\n";
$sData  = "data1A;data1B;data1C;\ndata2A;data2B;data2C;\ndata3A;data3B;data3C;\n";
$sEnd   = "END;";

$iPadLength = 8;
$iResponseLength = strlen($sBegin) + strlen($sData) + strlen($sEnd) + $iPadLength + strlen(";\n");

$sResponse = $sBegin . str_pad($iResponseLength, $iPadLength, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ";\n" . $sData . $sEnd;
echo $sResponse;
```

This solution looks very dirty to me. Mostly I don't like the padding part because the the response data can grow and the padding length can get too small which would cause calculation errors.

I would like to know if there is a better solution for doing this, WITHOUT changing the basic structure of the response.

Comment: Well...the whole thing is pretty dirty. The data length part is definitely not the worst of it. ;) The easiest solution probably would be to put the length before the `BEGIN;` and then only take the length of the string between `BEGIN;` and `END;` into consideration. Seems much more reasonable to me anyway.

Comment: get the length then trim the first line of the response (after the BEGIN)

Comment: @TillHelge I know. I don't like it too. The whole thing wasn't my idea, but I have to work with it :-/ Unfortunately I'm not allowed to change the structure. So I have to put the response length on the second line

Comment: Don't mess around with legacy code. If nobody pays to to replace it with a proper solution, don't touch it. You will not make it any better and in most cases fiddling around will just break it.

Comment: @Waygood I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you be more specific?

Comment: leave the code as it is. Then when it comes to processing it. `explode("\n",$data,3)` the data. which will give an array of `BEGIN;`, `00000087;`, and `the rest`. re-add the BEGIN\n to `the rest` and you now have data of length 87

Comment: @Waygood I think you didn't get the point :-) Or I still don't understand you :-) The problem is, that the length of the second line is also taken into account during the calculation.

Comment: So `actual length` is 87-8 (after we remove the 2nd line) even if the value removed is more than 8 characters

Comment: @Waygood The response length without the second line would be 87 - 10. Because of the semicolon and the \n (LINE FEED) at the end of the second line.